# character (0) after scraping webpage in read_html

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, webharvest, data-harvest

I'm trying to scrape "1,335,000" from the screenshot below (the number is at the bottom of the screenshot). I wrote the following code in R.

```
t2<-read_html("https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/fortune500/")
employee_number <- t2 %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
  xml2::xml_find_all("//*[contains(@class, 'info__value--2AHH7')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
```

However, when I call "employee_number", it gives me "character(0)". Can anyone help me figure out why?

[image]

Comment: The first line of the body says this: "<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to view this site.</noscript>", it looks like you will need to use Rselenium.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave2e, could you please elaborate on why Rselenium can solve the problem?

Comment: @XianZhao:  The page doesn't include that div until after the Javascript runs.  RSelenium will run the Javascript (it simulates a complete browser), rvest will just download the initial page.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave2e pointed the page uses `javascript`, thus can't make use of `rvest`.

```
url = "https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/fortune500/"
#launch browser 
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)

remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[12]/div[2]') %>% 
  html_text()
[1] "1,335,000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded dynamically from a `script` tag. No need for expense of a browser. You could either extract the entire JavaScript object within the `script`, pass to `jsonlite` to handle as JSON, then extract what you want, or, if just after the employee count, regex that out from the response text.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)

page <- read_html('https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/fortune500/')

data <- page %>% html_element('#preload') %>% html_text() %>% 
  stringr::str_match(. , "PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*);") %>% .[, 2] %>% jsonlite::parse_json()

print(data$components$page$`/company/amazon-com/fortune500/`[[6]]$children[[4]]$children[[3]]$config$employees)

#shorter version
print(page %>%html_text() %>% stringr::str_match('"employees":"(\\d+)?"') %>% .[,2] %>% as.integer() %>% format(big.mark=","))
```